# Spring batch - How to read Item property inside a bean creating a FlatFileItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm having the following problem:

I have the following bean being created in my configuration class

```
    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<MyItem> outputFileWriter() {
        DateTimeFormatter dateDefaultFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
        DateTimeFormatter hourDefaultFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss");
        
        String outputFile = "arq33" + MyEnum.valueOf(((String) executionContext.get("myProperty")).substring(4, 6)) 
                                         + dateDefaultFormatter.format(LocalDate.now()) 
                                         + hourDefaultFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now());
                
        Resource exportFileResource = new FileSystemResource(folderOutput + outputFile); 
          
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<MyItem>()
                .name("outputFileWriter")
                .lineAggregator(new MyFileLineAggregator(outputFile))
                .resource(exportFileResource)
                .build();
    }
```

I need to create a file with a certain pattern in naming, but that file name depends on a property of the MyItem class, how can I make the FlatFileItemWriter able to read a property of the Item that will write to the file?

I tried to use the executionContext, but I only get null (I put the executionContext in the configuration class itself):

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

@Value("#{jobExecution.executionContext}")
    private ExecutionContext executionContext;
   ...
```

I also thought about creating a custom FlatFileItemWriter, but I don't know if it's possible to create, I didn't find anything on the forum, only ItemWriter.

```
@StepScope
public class OutputFileWriter extends StepExecutionListenerSupport {
        
    @Value("${folder.output}")
    private String folderOutput;
    
    @Value("#{jobParameters['myProperty']}")
    private String test;
    
    DateTimeFormatter dateDefaultFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
    DateTimeFormatter hourDefaultFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss");
    
    String outputFile = "arq33" + MyEnum.valueOf(test.substring(4, 6)) 
                                     + dateDefaultFormatter.format(LocalDate.now()) 
                                     + hourDefaultFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now());
    
    private Resource exportFileResource = new FileSystemResource(folderOutput + outputFile);
         
    public FlatFileItemWriter<MyItem> writer() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<MyItem> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<MyItem>();
        writer.setResource(exportFileResource);
         
        writer.setAppendAllowed(true);
         
        writer.setLineAggregator(new MyFileLineAggregator(outputFile));
        
        return writer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The item writer bean definition method is executed at configuration time, but the actual reading of the item happens at runtime, so it is not possible to use the execution context (runtime information) to configure the writer.

The dynamic information needed to configure the writer in your case comes from one item. What you can do is create a preparation step that reads that information and puts it in the execution context, then configure a step scoped writer to read the information from the execution context. You can find an example here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#step-scope